# Additional Help When Mouse Hovering Over wx.MessageBox Or wx.MessageDialog

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I am updating a piece of software that makes extensive use of wx.MessageBox and wx.MessageDialog. The functionality I want to add is that if a user hovers over either for a predefined period additional Help information appears, e.g. a copy of the relevant paragraph from the manual that the users tend not to read!

Thank you for any help...

Comment: Unclear as to why my question was voted down. I have gone through two Python programming and a wxPython book besides Googling for an answer but have not found anything directly relevant to wx.MessageBox and wx.MessageDialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a `wx.Timer` that would pop up the additional help information. Then I would bind to wx.EVT_MOTION and reset the timeout of the wx.Timer object any time the mouse moves. If the user stops moving the mouse for the predetermined amount of time, the event handler that is bound to the timer object will be called and the pop up will appear.

The only caveat that occurs to me is that the MessageBox (and possibly the MessageDialog) may not pay any attention to EVT_MOTION. You'll have to play around and see. If they don't work, replace them with the generic version or roll your own with a wx.Dialog.

Comment: Found out that neither Message.Box nor Message.Dialog pay attention to mouse movement being modals. Investigating either "rolling my own" or using  wx.html.HtmlWindow with a "clickable" link to an HTML help file...

Comment: Don't forget to check out the generic message dialog: `wx.lib.agw.genericmessagedialog`. There are some examples in the wxPython demo.